# Android Studio Freezes

Tags: crash, android-studio, ubuntu-14.04, freeze

I use Android Studio 0.8.6 for Android Development, and when I'm editing a file, it will freeze, and I have to restart computer to close it, since System Monitor (I am on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) won't close it.  It's always the same file I'm editing, this never happens with any other file.  It shouldn't matter, but the name of the file is `sun_vertex_shader.glsl`.  There's no error, or log output, or anything.

Here's exactly what happens - I'm typing in the file, the cursor freezes, stops blinking, and the mouse pointer is an I-beam, no matter where in the window I move it.  The window doesn't close when I press the X, and when I restart my computer and open Android Studio again, I start editing the file and seconds later, it happens again.

I know you probably can't help me without any error logs, but I couldn't find any.  If you know where I could find them, I will post them here.

Comment: Always it is worth to check File -> Invalidates Caches/Restart. (And I don't have other ideas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what is causing this: the GLSL plugin I downloaded from [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6993?pr=) is causing Studio to freeze, as I have read in the comments.

Comment: Yes, this was indeed that plugin (which android studio asked me to install by default when creating a glsl file).. Did you find any other plug in which works? Just saw this one: https://github.com/Manabu-GT/glsl-gradle-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Please check your system Date/Time and correct it, this problem occurred if your system date does not match with current date.